# How to stop all events one html element can listen to?

Tags: javascript

Assume that there is `div` block, inside that block are many elements and they will fire many events. I don't want those events continuing bubble up, or listeners outside the `div` block may process wrong events with the same names. Can I make this without listening to bunch of events and stop them one by one?

Comment: All of one type, or different kinds of events?

Comment: Shouldn't one click handler on that container div with `e.stopPropagation();` stop all the events from within from bubbling past?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, most of them are different types

Comment: I don't think there's a way to create a listener for all events. For any particular event you can do what @tymeJV suggests, but you'll have to list all the events.

Comment: You can make a array of event-names that might happen, hopefully you know which events your app uses ;) Then have a small script loop through the array and `myDiv.addEventListener(myArray[i], function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });`

Comment: @tymeJV Yes I am using these solution, but what if I don't know which types of events may be fired? Is there any method to detect them?

Comment: One solution would be to make the `div` an `iframe` instead, if that doesn't mess about with your page structure too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must listen to every events individually and stop their propagation using `e.stopPropagation()`, where `e` is the event object. There's no way to listen to every events at once and unless you have a very specific subset of events, I wouldn't take this approach.

The most common way to handle bubbling events correctly is to validate the target element (`e.target`) and ignore accordingly.

For exemple, you could check if `e.target === e.currentTarget` to know if the event came from a child or not.

```js
var logEl = document.getElementById('log');

document.getElementById('parent').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    log('event comes from child? ' + (e.target !== e.currentTarget));
});

function log(msg) {
    logEl.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    logEl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
}
```

```css
#parent, #parent > div {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#parent {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
Click inside the boxes

<div id="parent">
    parent
    <div>child</div>
</div>

<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: OK I got it...But I am using Polymer and all events who fire inside an element's shadow their `e.target` are the same...

Comment: @ZhengyangLi Hum well, that would be another question then =P Could  you explain exactly what's the issue and why you are trying to accomplish this? The DOM is shadowed to preserve encapsulation and your code shouldn't have to know the internal structure of a component to use it. Therefore, something tells me you are doing something wrong or you are trying to reach into a component internals because that component is not flexible enough for your needs.

Comment: Ah, you are right, I should not manipulate the inner behavior :)