# Stop all events of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to stop all events of input, select, textarea . If there is an event on click or on focus of an input box then it should not work. When i click on input box, no event should be triggered. There should be no focus on input or textarea. If i click on select then it should not open (do not disable it, use preventDefault()) and i also need a button, on clicking that button the events which we stopped should be working again.

```html
First:
<input class='test1' type='text' value='1' /></br></br>

Second:
<select class='test2'>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select></br></br>

Third:
<textarea class='test3'>Hi all</textarea></br></br>

Fourth:
<input class='test4' type='text' value='4' />
```

```js
$(".test1").on("click", function (e) {
    alert('click on test1');
});

$(".test2").on("click", function (e) {
    alert('click on test2');
});

$(".test3").on("click", function (e) {
    alert('click on test3');
});

$(".test4").on("click", function (e) {
    alert('click on test4');
});

$("input").on("click", function (e) {
    alert('click on input');
});

$("input").bind("click", function (e) {
    alert('click on input (bind)');
});

$("input").hover(function (e) {
    alert('hover on input');
});

$("input").on("focus", function (e) {
    alert('focus on input');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/15termi/kLLjvkj2/4/)

Comment: Why do you not want to disable the elements? The behaviour you describe is ***exactly*** what it does. `$(element).prop('disabled', true);` You can re-enable the elements before form submission, if that's your concern.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop all events one html element can listen to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654124/how-to-stop-all-events-one-html-element-can-listen-to)

Answer (score 1):

you could use someting like this

```
var enabled = false;
$('input, textarea, select ').on('mousedown click focus', function(e) {
    if(!enabled){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.blur();
        window.focus();
    }
});
$("#enable-btn").on("click", function(e){
    enabled = !enabled;
    var text = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(text == "Enable" ? "Disable" : "Enable");
});
```

[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vasilenicusor/6hLfsr6q/2/)

---

**Edit after comment**

To prevent other functions attached to events, you need to check if state is disabled or not. 
Here you have the updated example.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="id1" />
<select>
    <option val="0">Val 0</option>
    <option val="1">Val 1</option>
    <option val="2">Val 2</option>
</select>
 <textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea> 
<input type="button" id="enable-btn" value="Enable" />
<div id="log"></div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var enabled = false;
$('input, textarea, select ').on('mousedown click focus', function(e) {
    if(!enabled){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.blur();
        window.focus();
    }
});
$("#enable-btn").on("click", function(e){
    enabled = !enabled;
    var text = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(text == "Enable" ? "Disable" : "Enable");
});

$("select").on("click",function(e){
    if (!enabled){       
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    $("#log").html("Select clicked");    
});
$("input").on("click",function(e){
    if (!enabled){       
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    $("#log").html("Input clicked");    
});
```

[Updated JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vasilenicusor/6hLfsr6q/5/)

Comment: but if i use on click on an input element or any other element then it also should not work.
$('input').on('click', function(e){
    alert('hi');
});

Answer (score 0):

Although many years later, I still didn't find an easy way to temporarily stop all events on an element if you're using jQuery.

In my case, I was using jQuery and Bootstrap and wanted to be sure that the user couldn't close a modal while submitting a form. I used this code on the modal (as the element) to stop the modal from closing but it should work for any element.

Start with the element you're using:

```
let elem = $("#id")[0];
```

To temporarily remove all events:

```
elem.savedEvents = [];
let events = $._data(elem, "events");
for (let ev in events) {
    elem.savedEvents[ev] = events[ev];
    events[ev] = [];
}
```

To restore all events:

```
let events = $._data(elem, "events");
for (let ev in events)
    events[ev] = elem.savedEvents[ev];
elem.savedEvents = [];
```

Good luck!